# Good session practices

Tags: authentication, cookies, session-management

What are some good practices for ensuring logins, session IDs and session content are secure for a website?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- Use a database for sessions.
- Regenerate the session on when the
  permissions change (e.g., when a user
  logs in).
- Regenerate the session on every page
  load (optional).
- Don't expose the session ID in the
  URL.
- Don't expose any sensitive data to the session.

Comment: Only use the session through secure transport, otherwise someone could sniff the cookie and hijack the session.

Comment: Alternative to the Regenerate note on page load above, if the previous pages actions(urls) are invalidated then it is a good thing for certain cases.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to VirtuosiMedia's list:

- Use TLS (SSL) across the entire site. Use the HSTS header.
- Use a session cookie, rather than adding a session token to every link-href and form-action.
- Use the `secure` and `httpOnly` flags on the cookie.
- Use the `X-Frame-Options` header.
- Keep the content of the session minimal. E.g., store only the user-id. If caching is needed, cache in a general caching layer, not the session.
- Cryptographically sign the session cookie with a secret key known only to the server. Include an expiration datetime in the signed data. Check the signature and the expiration at the server on every request.

Comment: "_Cryptographically sign the session cookie with a secret key known only to the server._" If the cookie contains only the session-id (the key in the database of sessions on the server), how it that helpful?

Comment: Firstly, is the session-id generated by a cryptgraphically-strong PRNG, and suitably long as to be unguessable and unforgeable? Secondly, it is more important for those who session data in cookies.

Answer (score 8):

Expire your session after a reasonable amount of time...  Delete the session out of whatever your using as a repository so it can't be re-used...

Answer (score 6):

don't save password or other user information except user id to the session.

Comment: So don't use WinForms auth? ;)

Answer (score 6):

Implement [DNSSec](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=dnssec) to protect your HTTPS session [from attacks over Wifi,](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6827/396) or public networks including [hardwired/switched](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/7761/396).

Use [HTTPS only](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/7790/396) for cookies that don't need Javascript access

Use the Secure attribute for all others cookies

Don't allow [3rd party javascript on your site](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4928/396)

Similar to the above, [don't serve advertisements](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/7840/396) on your site